# HTML Colspan might be breaking this?

Tags: html, html-table

I've been working on a website for my friends and I've ran into an issue.
They asked to have the banner at the top wider, which is what I did and it caused this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/91xBu.jpg

This code here is the navbar section, I really want to get this part fixed, as I think I can figure out the rest just fine.

```
<table width="1400" border="0" height="100%" cellpadding="0"     cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="203" colspan="11" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
 <td width="58" height="184" valign="top"><img src="images/en_02.gif" width="58" height="184" /></td>
<td colspan="3"  valign="top"><img src="images/banner.png" width="1400" height="184" /></td>
<td width="58" valign="top"><img src="images/en_04.gif" width="58" height="184" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="19" valign="top"><img src="images/en_06.gif" width="58" height="19" /></td>

<td width="500"  valign="top"><img src="images/glow_ban.png" width="500" height="19" /></td><td width="800" align ="left" valign="top"><a      href="http://www.uafclan.com">
<img src="images/main.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/forums"><img src="images/forums.png" width="124" height="19" border="0"/></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/join"><img src="images/joins.png"width="125" height="19" border="0" /></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/member"><img src="images/member.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/staff"><img src="images/staff.png" width="125" height="19" border="0" /></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/rosters"><img src="images/rosters.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/></a><td width="72" valign="top"><img src="images/right_glow.png"height="19" /></td>
<td valign="top"><img src="images/en_17.gif" width="58" height="19" /></td>
</tr>
</table>    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have an unclosed td.

Answer (score 0):

There was an unclosed **td** tag. Try this code block in place of yours:

```
<table width="1400" border="0" height="100%" cellpadding="0"     cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="203" colspan="11" valign="top">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
    <td width="58" height="184" valign="top"><img src="images/en_02.gif" width="58" height="184" /></td>
    <td colspan="3"  valign="top"><img src="images/banner.png" width="1400" height="184" /></td>
    <td width="58" valign="top"><img src="images/en_04.gif" width="58" height="184" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="19" valign="top"><img src="images/en_06.gif" width="58" height="19" /></td>
    <td width="500"  valign="top"><img src="images/glow_ban.png" width="500" height="19" /></td>
    <td width="800" align ="left" valign="top"><a      href="http://www.uafclan.com"><img src="images/main.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/forums"><img src="images/forums.png" width="124" height="19" border="0"/></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/join"><img src="images/joins.png"width="125" height="19" border="0" /></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/member"><img src="images/member.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/staff"><img src="images/staff.png" width="125" height="19" border="0" /></a><a href="http://www.uafclan.com/rosters"><img src="images/rosters.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/></a></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><img src="images/right_glow.png"height="19" /></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="images/en_17.gif" width="58" height="19" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem sadly, but it's still good to catch that. Thanks. That could be a contributer to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code indented which might make it easier to read. Your 'container' table has a width set at 1400. The sum of the widths in the first row of your inside table adds up to 1516 and the second row 1437. I wonder if it's the extra width pushing things out of shape.

```
<table width="1400" border="0" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="203" colspan="11" valign="top">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="58" height="184" valign="top">
                        <img src="images/en_02.gif" width="58" height="184" />
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                        <img src="images/banner.png" width="1400" height="184" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="58" valign="top">
                        <img src="images/en_04.gif" width="58" height="184" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="19" valign="top">
                        <img src="images/en_06.gif" width="58" height="19" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="500"  valign="top">
                        <img src="images/glow_ban.png" width="500" height="19" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="800" align ="left" valign="top">
                        <a href="http://www.uafclan.com">
                            <img src="images/main.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.uafclan.com/forums">
                            <img src="images/forums.png" width="124" height="19" border="0"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.uafclan.com/join">
                            <img src="images/joins.png"width="125" height="19" border="0" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.uafclan.com/member">
                            <img src="images/member.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.uafclan.com/staff">
                            <img src="images/staff.png" width="125" height="19" border="0" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="http://www.uafclan.com/rosters">
                            <img src="images/rosters.png" width="125" height="19" border="0"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="72" valign="top">
                        <img src="images/right_glow.png"height="19" />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <img src="images/en_17.gif" width="58" height="19" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these blocks of code are causing the problem:

```
<td width="72" valign="top"><img src="images/right_glow.png"height="19" /></td>
<td valign="top"><img src="images/en_17.gif" width="58" height="19" /></td>
```

I wasn't able to get it working perfectly, but I think I improved the situation (I'm not totally sure what your desired end result is, but I think it's just to have it all line up):

```
<td valign="top" width="125">
<img src="images/right_glow.png" width="125" height="19" />
</td>
<td valign="top" width="58">
<img src="images/en_17.gif" width="58" height="19" />
```

You can see the results here:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/3o26Lwhf/
Try cutting and pasting your original code in to see the difference.  Good luck!